# files watcher for a file in a folder with nodejs

Tags: node.js, filesystems

My use-case is to watch on file addition on filesystem (unix) with NodeJS, the addition happens as copying a folder contains a file inside the "watched" folder,
the problem I get event only for the added directory and not for the file that is inside.I tried to use several watch libraries "watchr" and "node-watch" but both behave the same.

for example I watch "to_watch" folder and copy in there "temp" folder contains random named file, I got event only for "temp"

> watch successful on to_watch
>
> the file to_watch/temp was created..

Answer (score 0):

After trying several libraries, I found one which fulfill my request, "chokidar"

> npm install chokidar --save

```
var chokidar = require('chokidar');

// One-liner for current directory, ignores .dotfiles
chokidar.watch('.', {ignored: /(^|[\/\\])\../}).on('all', (event, path) => {
  console.log(event, path);
});
```